# How do you get a PowerSoft report to resolve a PowerBuilder global function

Tags: function, global, powerbuilder

I currently work in an environment where reports must be emailed to users as a PowerSoft file.
There is a global PowerBuilder function which is used on a computed column my datawindow.   This datawindow becomes the final psr report.
In my testing the function is resolved fine, when run live.  However, when the user runs the report, it sends the psr to their respective email address.  (I didn't design the system)
When they open the psr, the function is not resolved.
Does anyone know if it is possible to wrap this function into the datawindow or into the final psr?

Thanks,
Glenn

Comment: What does the global function do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global function must be available through the PSR viewer. Period. The users' PSR viewer must have that same global function in order for the datawindow to render correctly.

There is a way to work around it, but it's rather tedious. Basically, you need to replace your computed field (that uses the global function) with a SQL column. Update your SQL to include a dummy column of the appropriate datatype. When you finish retrieving, get the value of your computed field (Look up "Describe ('evaluate')") and do a SetItem() on your dummy column. Display the column instead of the computed field.